# Is there any way for define my own "onSomeFunction" for an element in jquery?

Tags: jquery, function, any

Is there any way for defining my own "onSomeFunction" in jQuery?
I have a function to understand that an element is scrolled to view or not. its name is "isScrolledToView()" and returns true or false.
Now I want to define something like code below.
its just an example. I want to do it for any other functions like this:

```
$("div.myDiv").on("scrolledToView", function() {
    alert("Scrolled To View")
})
```

please help me with this.

Comment: You want to know about [`IntersectionObserver`](https://github.com/w3c/IntersectionObserver/tree/master/polyfill).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not that easy! But yes it's possible.
But now, let's look for an easy way:
In this case, we can simply use:

```
let onScrollIntoView = () => {
    // do some stuff...
}
window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
    const isVisible = true // or false// Chek if that element is in the viewport
    if (isVisible) { onScrollIntoView() }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

So you can call the function on scroll event as like below

```
$("div.myDiv").on( 'scroll', function(){
   scrolledToView(); /* This is your custom function */
});
```

Once you call the function the function will execute only on scroll event and you can do whatever you want from that function.